# Dativ vs. Akkusativ "Sieh ... Schrank!"

Tags: dative, accusative, wechselpraeposition

In einem Lehrwerk stehen folgende Sätze:

> Person 1: Wo ist mein Pullover? Ich finde ihn nicht.
>
> Person 2: Sieh doch mal **..... Schrank**!

> Person 1: Wo sind meine Schuhe?
>
> Person 2: Sieh doch mal unter **… Bett**!

Ich habe Schwierigkeiten beim Bestimmen, ob es sich hier um den Akkusativ (man richtet seinen Blick in irgendeine Richtung, also wohin?) oder den Dativ handelt.

Im Lösungsheft steht

> Sieh doch mal **im** Schrank!

Deutsch ist nicht meine Muttersprache, aber aus dem Bauchgefühl heraus würde ich so gern am Satzende "nach" hinzufügen:

*Sieh doch mal im Schrank nach.*

Hier ist der Dativgebrauch für mich eindeutig.

Wie sieht es jedoch mit den oberen Sätzen aus? Ist der im Lösungsheft angegebene Satz tatsächlich korrekt?

Vielen Dank!

Answer (score 6):

Es sollte eigentlich heißen: "**Guck** doch mal im Schrank". Das passt gut mit dem Dativ. Aber: "Sieh doch mal **in den** Schrank." Also Akkusativ mit zusätzlicher Präposition.

Der Satz "Sieh doch mal im Schrank" oder "Sieh doch mal in dem Schrank" (was ja dasselbe ist) ist kein korrekter deutscher Satz weil sehen etwas mit zielgerichteter Bewegung zu tun hat (anders als *gucken*).

Bei "Sieh doch mal im Schrank nach" liegt ein anders Verb vor, nämlich das trennbare Verb *nachsehen*. Das verhält sich gleich wie *gucken*. Das tun man an einem Ort (ohne etwas, das auf ein Ziel gerichtet ist), aber *sehen* + Präposition (in, unter, auf, ...) ist etwas zielgerichtetes, will also den Akkusativ.

Bei 2. Beispiel ist die Präposition schon vorgegeben, da fehlt nur noch der Artikel, und der muss auch hier im Akkusativ stehen: "Sieh doch mal unter **das** Bett." (Lenke deine "Sehstrahlen" so aus, dass sie an einem bestimmten Ziel enden.) Mit einem anderen Verb geht aber auch Dativ: "Guck doch mal unter **dem** Bett." (Nimm etwas wahr, das an einem Ort ist.)

Comment: Die Antwort scheint zu implizieren, dass "Guck doch mal in den Schrank." nicht in Ordnung wäre, was ich so nicht bestätigen kann.

Answer (score 4):

Als Muttersprachler teile ich Dein Sprachgefühl:

> Sieh doch mal im Schrank **nach**!

macht einen vollständigeren Eindruck als der Vorschlag aus dem Lösungsheft.

> Sieh doch mal *in den Schrank*

wäre die Standardkonstruktion mit der Richtungsangabe, die den Akkusativ verlangt. *In* ist eine so genannte Wechselpräposition, die je nach Formulierung einen der beiden Fälle verlangt.

Falls es statt des Schranks ein offen einsehbares Möbel wäre, ist auch ein Ausruf wie

> Sieh doch mal: im Regal (liegt er doch / sehe ich ihn liegen)!

möglich.